# How Do I Cast a Variable With Dot Notation? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference

I am referencing the (speed for an object in my game) variable from one script to another. There are 3 parts to it: the `min` var, the `max` var (`min` and `max` are used to generate a random number for the speed), and the `fallSpd` var (the random number generated from `min` and `max`). They are all floats, but when I reference the variable `max` and `min` on line 16, I get this error:

```
Assets\Destruction.cs(16,22): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

So I cast `min` and it allows it. However, when I cast `max` to `double`, it gives this error:

```
Assets\Destruction.cs(16,9): error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer
```

So I don't know how I'm supposed to cast it.

Here's the code I'm referencing (only important parts included):

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
    
public class Losing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] Addictions = new GameObject[5];

    public Transform[] Transforms = new Transform[5];

    public static float fallSpd;

    public static float min = 0.1f;
    public static float max = 0.4f;

    private bool Lost = false;

    private void Start() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (Lost != true)
            {
                Transforms[i].position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-4, 4), Random.Range(12, 31));
                ChangeSpd();
            }  
        }
    }

    public void ChangeSpd()
    {
        fallSpd = (float) Random.Range(min, max) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

And the code that references this script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
        
public class Destruction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] Transforms = new Transform[5];

    public GameObject PrayingMan;

    public Losing losing;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) 
    {
        Losing.min = Losing.fallSpd; 
        (double) Losing.max = Losing.min + 0.3; // i get all the errors on this line!
        print("min: " + Losing.min + "max: " + Losing.max + "speed: " + Losing.fallSpd);
        PrayingMan.GetComponent<Losing>().ChangeSpd();
    }
}
```

How to fix this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it reversed, your variable is a `float` but when you do `Losing.min + 0.3` you are creating a double, by default .net assumes `double` if no decimal modifier is specified.

You have two options, cast the value to float or use a modifier.
To do the cast you would do:

```
Losing.max = (float)(Losing.min + 0.3);
```

But that is a waste of processing, the best is to specify the float modifier:

```
Losing.max = Losing.min + 0.3f;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check this as the correct answer!

Comment: @JMasterBoi when? ^^

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need to do any casting at all. Just change the ”0.3” to be ”0.3f”. The f indicates that it is a float, but if there is no f it will be considered a double.